# unique xpath combined two attributes

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

Ho do I make unique xpath to let the robot locate into second field?

i used this but failed:

```
Click     //div[contains(@class,'ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search') and contains(text(),'Select Source(s)')]
```

First Field:

```
<div class="ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search">
    <div class="ant-select-selector">
        <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow">
            <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow-item ant-select-selection-overflow-item-suffix" style="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="ant-select-selection-search" style="width: 3px;">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="search" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_9_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_9_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_9_list_7" value="" id="rc_select_9" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false" readonly="" unselectable="on">
                        <span class="ant-select-selection-search-mirror" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">attribute(s)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

second field:

```
<div class="ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search">
    <div class="ant-select-selector">
        <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow">
            <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow-item ant-select-selection-overflow-item-suffix" style="opacity: 1;">
                <div class="ant-select-selection-search" style="width: 3px;">
                    <input autocomplete="off" type="search" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_10_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_10_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_10_list_0" value="" id="rc_select_10" style="opacity: 0;" aria-expanded="false" readonly="" unselectable="on">
                        <span class="ant-select-selection-search-mirror" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Select Source(s)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this xpath works (when I test at chrome developer console, it is detected) but when robot executed the script, it does not really click into the field. the drop-down list does not display.

```
Click     //div[@class="ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search"]
```

error:

```
    FAIL
Message:    TimeoutError: locator.click: Timeout 10000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//span[contains(@class,'ant-select-selection-placeholder') and contains(text(),'Select Source(s)')] >> nth=0"
  selector resolved to hidden <span class="ant-select-selection-placeholder">Select Source(s)</span>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
    element is not stable - waiting...
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  checking that element receives pointer events at (1080.4,304.7)
  <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow">…</div> intercepts pointer events
retrying click action, attempt #1
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  checking that element receives pointer events at (1080.4,304.7)
    [ Message content over the limit has been removed. ]
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  checking that element receives pointer events at (1080.4,304.7)
  <div class="ant-select-selection-overflow">…</div> intercepts pointer events
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not so far from solution to select **the uniq div**

text equals:

```
//div[contains(@class,'ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search') and .//span[text()='Select Source(s)']]
```

if you want the expression contains:

```
//div[contains(@class,'ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search') and .//span[contains(.,'Select Source(s)')]]
```

Comment: thanks. i am facing challenges on reconstructing xpath. any good documentation for self-learning please recommend.

Comment: you could begin with https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/practical-xpath-for-web-scraping/

Answer (score 0):

You can give an index according to your best match like

```
(//*[@class='ant-select SearchPrompter_advInput__3P9Jf ant-select-multiple ant-select-allow-clear ant-select-show-search'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `span` tag and `parent` keyword in the xpath to find the required `div` tag element.

As per the HTML Code, Xpath would be something like this.

```
//span[contains(text(),'Select Source')]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div
```